# c# chart axis formatting - new line symbol

Tags: c#, charts, format

Is there any way to add a new line character to axis' label? My axis value type is DateTime and currently I display hh:mm format, but I want to add "dd" below to indicate which day is it. I tried to format the axis like that:

```
HH:mm\r\ndd
```

but it's displayed as eg. 11:45rn22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `Axis.LabelStyle.Format` property:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm\ndd";
```

I've tried the code above and it seems to work.

Comment: Actually it works, thank you! I thought setting it in designer would be enough...